# SVG file excessive white space

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, white-space

I've created a vector using Adobe Illustrator CS5. The actual size is supposedly 30x30 px. For some reason, whenever I save it as an SVG file. It produces a file that is not 30x30 px. My vector is in it (on the upper left) but it has a lot of whitespace that I just couldn't figure how to remove.

- I've already tried cleaning my vector, checking if there are stray elements possibly contributing to the bigger space.
- Also tried every possible settings written out there but still couldn't get the 30x30 that I want.

Here's a screenshot of the saved file :
[image]

Here's the actual SVG file :
http://katerinapetrova.com/11.svg

Comment: Could you post the SVG file for us to have a look at please?

Comment: Hi Jackson! I've pasted the link of the svg file above. SVG is not allowed to be uploaded here. thanks!

Comment: I opened your SVG and it looked fine to me ([here's a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/ce3pR9T.png)).  I'm not sure how you're getting such a large amount of white space around the shape in yours.

Comment: How are you previewing that SVG?

Answer (score 8):

- Select All (Cmd/Ctrl A)
- Object > Artboards > Fit to Artwork Bounds
- File > Save As
- Format: SVG

This sets the origin to: x="0px" y="0px"

The viewBox to: "0 0 [Your image's width] [Your image's height] "

And "enable-background:new 0 0 [Your image's width] [Your image's height];"

Comment: Thanks, you saved me hours!

Comment: Not working in my case :(

Answer (score 2):

I had issues with excess white space above and below my SVGs on a pdf editor and tried theship's suggestion and that got me halfway to my goal. The other part that was messing me up was the auto-checked "Responsive" checkbox in the SVG save as dialog box. Unchecking that box put the SVG up at the top of the document without white space. Provided, I was using 2018's version of Illustrator CC.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!